# Excepion with MysqlCommand and "SET @q:" variable C#?

Tags: c#, mysql, mysql-parameter

i have this code:

```
using (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection cn = new   
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection(
            Properties.Settings.Default.CONNNConnectionString))
        {
            cn.Open();
            MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand cm = new 
            MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand();
            cm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cm.Connection = cn;
cm.CommandText="CREATE  PROCEDURE `GetMovement`(RefArtt vARCHAR(20),idos INTEGER) "+
"BEGIN "+
"SET @Qt=0; "SELECT * ,@Qt:=@Qt+qteliv-qtesor as stock FROM tableInOut;"+
"End";
cm.ExecuteNonQuery();}
```

> Exception :    You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MySQL  server version for the right syntax to
>   use near ''@Qt'=0; SELECT * ...

Comment: have you declared @Qt?

Answer (score 0):

Union should to write the same names or alias
So, you can modify the alias to be the same in two select statement

Comment: i added the query as procedure and then call it from c# code it work.